# Not able to upload image file on server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

My file picked from gallery and set to imageview but after click on upload button  not able upload my file on server

I am using local host,my server side code is correct because image is uploading via postman

```
File file = new File(mediaPath);


        // parsing media type file
        RequestBody requestBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);


        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("input_img", file.getName(), requestBody1);

        ServiceApi call = ClientApi.getData().create(ServiceApi.class);
        Call<ResponseData> data = call.update(fileToUpload1);

        data.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response)
            {

                ResponseData data = response.body();
                if(data.getStatus().equals("true"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
//                Log.d("data",data.getUpdateUserData().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check once",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: did you debug and check what is happening?

Comment: yes i debug the code,but nothing shown there

Comment: Post the `update` method of `ServiceApi` class

Comment: @Multipart
    @POST("user")
    Call<ResponseData> update(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);

Comment: Are you sure the mediaPath in the file = new File(mediaPath) is a vaild file ? Please check that also. I think your upload code is right I guess.

Comment: yes its correct